# i cant catkin_make in my work space . i heve this error : howcan i fix that?

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i cant  catkin_make in my work space . i heve this error :  howcan i fix that ??

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/cfe4d7a28fd91cc0ba613b02b3e93b9e

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247802/i-cant--catkin_make-in-my-work-space-.-i-heve-this-error-:--howcan-i-fix-that-??/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As to your problem: it looks like a version mismatch between your version of Gazebo and the one expected by the Kobuki packages. Are you sure you have the correct versions?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0